# Stripe 3d secure token to customer and then charge

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments, payment

I try to figure out Stripe's system.
This is what I am trying now:

- Generate a 3D Secure token with the payment of 49.00 EUR.
- When I receive the token back (successfully) I create the customer with "source" as the 3D Secure token.
- Hereafter I charge the customer (customerId). But.... it doesn't work.

If I remove the create customer and just charge, it works fine. But I need the card to be attached to the customer for later use as well.

Can Anybody help me out here?

```
//Load private keys
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'XXX'
);
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('XXX');


//On callback the 3d secure token is $_GET['token']
if($_GET['success']=="true")
{

//Create customer and attach the card.
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
  'email' => mt_rand(111,999). 'aaa.user@example.com',
  'source' => $_GET['token'],
  'name'=> 'Je2ns',
  'phone' => '+4403395848585',
  'shipping' => [
    'name' => 'Jen3ny R3osen',
    'address' => [
      'line1' => '1234 Ma3in Street',
      'city' => 'San Fran3cisco',
      'state' => 'CA',
      'country' => 'FR',
      'postal_code' => '924111',
    ],
  ],
]);



//Charge the customer (this doesnt work???)
$lastCharge = $stripe->charges->create([
  'amount' => 49 * 100,
  'currency' => 'eur',
  'source' => $customer->id,
  'description' => 'Payment for product '.mt_rand(111,999),
]);


print_r($lastCharge);

exit;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .btn {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Cards</h1>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead><th>3d secure support</th><th>Card Number</th><th>CVC</th><th>Expiry Month</th><th>Expiry Year</th><th></th></thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>no support (American Express)</td><td>3782 822463 10005</td><td>123</td><td>12</td><td>2020</td><td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onClick('3782 822463 10005')">Try this card!</button></td></tr>
          <tr><td>optional (no authentication)</td><td>4242 4242 4242 4242</td><td>123</td><td>12</td><td>2020</td><td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onClick('4242 4242 4242 4242')">Try this card!</button></td></tr>
          <tr><td>optional (needs authentication)</td><td>4000 0000 0000 3055</td><td>123</td><td>12</td><td>2020</td><td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onClick('4000 0000 0000 3055')">Try this card!</button></td></tr>
          <tr><td>required</td><td>4000 0000 0000 3063</td><td>123</td><td>12</td><td>2020</td><td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onClick('4000 0000 0000 3063')">Try this card!</button></td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="col-12" id="iframe-payment"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
  <script>
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_51HlZKDHy9IqUyGdb3cTcBzS2taPiQ2lk9l541zYLeLIDqrpRjQ2CuKcInk44ODeD0ZLwormKKTo4UlbBAAUBIz7g00ePPikjd4')
  </script>
  <script src="js/api.js"></script>
  <script>
    /**
 * When we click on a card
 */
function onClick(cardNumber) {
  const paymentRequest = {
    cardNumber: cardNumber,
    expYear: '2024',
    expMonth: '12',
    cvc: '123',
    currency: 'EUR',
    amount: 49 * 100,
    nativeElement: document.querySelector('#iframe-payment')
  };
  
  paymentRequest.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'Loading... Please wait...';

  doPayment(paymentRequest).then((result) => {
    console.log('result --> ', result);
    paymentRequest.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'Success!!!! Your details are correct!!! :)';
    alert('Success: Token is: ' + result.id);
    location.href='?success=true&token='+result.id;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    paymentRequest.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'Ups! We can\t validate your details...';
    alert('Ups, something wrong, sorry! :(');
  });
}

</script>
```

[CHECK STRIPE CUSTOMER OBJECT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyf4A.png)

Response: [12-Nov-2020 14:09:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_KV5s9g0GJHuOe3) No such token: 'cus_INRMWJeybBDacX'

Comment: A `cus_*****` id is a Customer, not a Token. You already have a Customer object, but it's not clear from your currently shared code how you are creating that Customer.

Comment: Check now, updated with the client-side.

Comment: The underlying issue is still that you have a Customer object with (in this case) the id of `cus_INRMWJeybBDacX`. It has a Source/Card already attached to it. You can [retrieve the Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve?lang=php) and inspect it to verify. You don't need to convert a Token in any way (because you don't have a Token).

Comment: [default_source] => src_1HmhTpHy9IqUyGdbK7jIZuoc [id] => cus_INSOZwFGQpFztB